# Why is my main.xml invisible to the compiler?

Tags: android

I *do* have a \res\layout\main.xml file.

Yet, this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

...gives me the err msg, "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

in my Activity.java file.

What am I missing?

Alright, I see there is nothing in the project's Gen folder. What would cause it to not get populated?

Comment: I noticed some typos in my manifest file (had "permissions" spelled like "persimmon" or some such). Still, though, I get "main cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Comment: Do you have the correct files imported?

Comment: Let me be clear, Your activity class name is Activity.java?

Comment: @ClayShannon do you solve your problem?

Comment: "Let me be clear, Your activity class name is Activity.java?"

No, it is <Project Name> Activity.java

(where "<Project Name>" is the name of my project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps which helps me to resolve this problem.

1. Delete R.java (Eclipse will recreate it immediately. If not there is a problem with the code or layout)
2. Clean the project (Eclipse menu 'Project' & 'Clean'
3. Recompile the project

These steps resolve the problem with my work.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure there is nothing wrong in your Manifest file.

2) In eclipse, click project -> clean

3) If that didn't work, you still have something wrong in your manifest file. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Yes, I tired the "Clean" jazz - still no joy in Mudville.

Comment: If clean doesn't work, go back to step 1. The only reason resource ID's don't show up is because there is something wrong in the manifest. Eclipse doesn't show manifest errors for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

First Check your R.java file is generated or not. 
if not clean and build your project  even though file is not created then try to remove your last added xml file in layout. since If there is any error or problem in adding xml file R.java will not generated. Check your manifest file too.

Comment: My only xml files are AndroidManifest and main, and I DID find a superfluous "/" in the former; I Cleaned, and Built, but still get "main cannot be resolved or is not a field" here:   setContentView(R.layout.main);
and "Description Resource Path Location Type
The element type "manifest" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</manifest>" here:     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and rebuild the apk